# Why can `runBlocking` be invoked without providing a CoroutineContext, if there's no default value for it?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I always check the implementation of the things I use.

Currently I'm using an injection library that doesn't support suspensable functions (Koin), so, only (even if discouraged) for bootstrapping the app, I'm using runBlocking some times.

In order to have richer logs, I'm enriching the coroutine context with some info, yet that info is lost in most context changes (`launch`, `async`, and `runBlocking` among others).

Specially, given the fact that non-suspend methods don't have access to a CoroutineContext, I'm super curious where does `runBlocking` gets it from.

You can use `runBlocking` like:

```kotlin
runBlocking {...}
```

Yet, when I check its implementation, it has two parameters: a `CoroutineContext` and the suspend block to be executed. None of those parameters have default value, so why can I call it without passing it? I really don't get it!

Additionally, the page says that the default value is `EmptyCoroutineContext` but the code docs say something about an event loop.

So I ask again? Why can I call it without passing a value, and what's the actual default?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default `runBlocking()` starts with an empty coroutine context.

The fact that the `context` doesn't have a default value is indeed confusing and strange. I think (but I'm not 100% sure) this is because by ctrl+clicking on `runBlocking()` we go the implementation, so `actual` definition. But the code is compiled against the `expect` declaration. I didn't find an easy way to see `expect` declaration directly in IntelliJ, but it can be found [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/kotlinx-coroutines-core/concurrent/src/Builders.concurrent.kt):

```kotlin
public expect fun <T> runBlocking(context: CoroutineContext = EmptyCoroutineContext, block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> T): T
```

As we can see, `context` in this declaration has a default value. Still, this is really confusing when using IntelliJ.

And regarding the mentioned event loop: yes, `runBlocking()` creates (or re-uses) an event loop, but I don't see how it relates to the coroutine context.

Comment: As mentioned, when `runBlocking` is called w/o an explicit context, it gets an empty one. In the code for `runBlocking` you can see if there's no dispatcher present (`context["ContinuationInterceptor"]`) it creates a `BlockingEventLoop`.. otherwise, it tries to cast the dispatcher as an `EventLoop`, and if it can't do that it gets the existing `ThreadLocal` `BlockingEventLoop` if it can.

Answer (score 3):

Remember that the context you pass to a coroutine builder like `runBlocking` or `launch` is *not* the context that will actually become available inside the coroutine, but its *parent*. The builder adds its own items and merges them into the context you provided.

`runBlocking` uses its own dispatcher, which exists only during the lifetime of the `runBlocking` function call. You can find this dispatcher in the coroutine context available inside the body of `runBlocking`, for example using this code:

```kotlin
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking

fun main() {
    runBlocking {
        val ctxElems = coroutineContext.fold(mutableListOf<Pair<Any, Any>>()) { list, element ->
            list.also { it.add(element.key to element) }
        }
        for ((key, value) in ctxElems) {
            println("${key::class.qualifiedName}: $value")
        }
    }
}
```

This prints

```
kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineId.Key: CoroutineId(1)
kotlinx.coroutines.Job.Key: "coroutine#1":BlockingCoroutine{Active}@12843fce
kotlin.coroutines.ContinuationInterceptor.Key: BlockingEventLoop@3dd3bcd
```

(coroutine dispatchers belong to the broader category of continuation interceptors)

The other part of your question, why you don't have to pass in the seemingly non-default parameter, is answered elsewhere. Basically, it's an artifact of the IDE and the `expected` vs. `actual` declarations. The relevant declaration is the `expected` one, and `actual` is an implementation detail, but the IDE takes you to that one.